# SqlException must declare the scalar variable "@ID'

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error

> SqlException must declare the scalar variable "@ID"

Here is the code. I already tried to use different approach but still the same

```cs
try
{
    AdminPanel n = new AdminPanel();

    if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Student ID");
    }
    else
    {
        string commstring = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE studentno = @ID";

        using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(constring))
        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(commstring, connect))
        {
            comm.Connection.Open();

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox1.Text);

            SqlDataReader read = comm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            if (read.Read() == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The student ID you've entered doesn't have a library card yet.", "No Record");
            }
            else
            {
                checkIssue();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `studentno`? If it's an integer, I would suggest 1) specifying the parameter type directly; 2) converting to an integer in your code: e.g. using `comm.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);`. (You probably actually want to perform the conversion earlier with `int.TryParse` so you can provide a useful error message if the value isn't a number.)

Comment: Side point: you need to dispose `read` with a `using`. Don't block the thread with a message box while the connection is open. Avoid `AddWithValue`, specify parameter types and lengths explicitly. Don't `SELECT *` just what you need. In this case you only want to know existence, so just `SELECT 1`, then you can use `var studentExists = comm.ExecuteScalar() is int;` and avoid using a DataReadeer altogether

Answer (score 0):

I think you are lacking the datatype of **studentno**, the code should be like this :

(if **studentno** was int type:)

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DbType.Int32, textBox1.Text);

(if **studentno** was string type: )

comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DbType.String, textBox1.Text);